# using -sort in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to sort the input of the user with `sort` in a case (and function).
But I never used this before. Do I have to use an array or something?

For example the user does:

```
bash test.sh 50 20 35 50
```

Normally in my script this would happen:

```
ping c -1 "192.168.0.$i"
```

That results in

```
192.168.0.50
192.168.0.20
192.168.0.35
192.168.0.50
```

Now I want that the last numbers are sorted and also pinged from smallest to the biggest number like this: 20 35 50 and also that if you have 2 times the same number, the script only pings that number one time.

```
SortNumbers(){


}


...

case

-sort ) SortNumbers;;

esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=($(printf '%s\n' "$@"|sort -nu))
echo ${array[@]}
```

If you run `test.sh 34 1 45 1 5 6 6 6`, it will give output:

```
1 5 6 34 45
```

Now you can use the variable `$array` with a `for` loop like:

```
for i in ${array[@]};do
#do something with $i
done
```

Explanation:

The arguments of the script is piped to the command `sort` and the output is assigned into an array named `array`. The options `-n` is for numerical sort and `-u` is for unique.

Assumed complete code for you (for clarification):

```
#!/bin/bash
array=($(printf '%s\n' "$@"|sort -nu))
for i in ${array[@]};do
ping -c -1 "192.168.0.$i"
done
```

Using a function:

```
sortNumbers(){
array=($(printf '%s\n' "$@"|sort -nu))
}
sortNumbers 43 1 2 8 2 4 98 45
echo ${array[@]} ##this is just a sample use, you can put for loop here
```

So you can declare an array `array=($@)` at the begining of your script. then call the `sortNumbers` function with the arguments (remember to exclude `-sort` from the argument) when needed to sort them (it will change the variable `$array` with sorted content). Put the for loop outside the function so it takes whatever in the variable `$array` (sorted or unsorted), that way you will have it your way (choice to do sort or not).

Comment: So to ping my ip-addresses I only have to input ping c -1 "192.168.0.$i" in the for loop?
Like this: 
array=($(printf '%s\n' "$@"|sort -u))
SortNumbers(){
echo ${array[@]}
for i in $({array[@]};do
ping 192.168.0.$i
done

}
case
-sort ) SortNumbers;;
esac

Comment: No, you don't need to use the sortNumber function, and the echo.

Comment: @gladius I have added a complete code sample for your particular case, You don't need to use any function to do the sorting, it's just an extra line above your for loop.

Comment: okay, Tnx. But I use it in a case. So i will put the for.... - .. done in a function and the array in the begin of my script. So i can do this: bash test.sh -sort 50 40 80 20 for example

Comment: @gladius it won't work like that... I am updating my answer with a function solution...

Comment: tnx. I use this function and I added the for loop inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. copy the scripts arguments into an array
array=($@)
# 2. Set internal field separator to newline
IFS=$'\n'
# 3. pass the array contents to sort's stdin using here-string
sorted=($(sort <<<"${array[*]}"))
# 4. pass the output of sort to uniq utility using the same technique
uniq=($(uniq <<<"${sorted[*]}"))
# 5. print the final array
printf "%s\n" "${uniq[@]}"
```

[lcd047](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658042/lcd047)'s shorter version:

```
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -nu <<<"$*"))
set "${sorted[@]}"
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

Run result:

```
$> bash test.sh 3 2 1 45 45 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 1
1
2
3
4
45
```

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit please? I am new in shell scripting.

Comment: Or just `IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -nu <<<"$*")); set "${sorted[@]}"`

Comment: The point of `set "${sorted[@]}"` is to have the changes back in `$@`.  Try `printf '%s\n' "$@"`